# How to adjust divider witdh in vuetify component?

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js, nuxt.js

I have using Nuxt.js and Vuetify.js in my project.
I need to adjust v-divider width, so I tried to write css in my code.
But it didn't work.
Does anyone teach me how to change v-divider width in Vuetify components?

```
<template>
   <divider class="test"/>
</template>
<style lang="scss" scoped>
   .test{ width:100px}
</style>
```

Comment: Its my typo. Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally removed my comment. But yeah, just a typo of `<divider/>` instead of `<v-divider/>`. Happy Coding!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just a typo of `<divider/>` instead of `<v-divider/>`.

Alternatively (*and not really recommended*), you can set the width by specifying the width attribute of `<v-divider/>` since it uses [`<hr/>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr). However, this approach seems to be deprecated and the best approach is to style it using css.

```html
<v-divider width="100"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

vuetify `<v-divider>` uses border properties. So instead of width you should specify borders.

```js
const opts = {}
Vue.use(Vuetify)

new Vue ({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(opts),
})
```

```css
.test {
       border-width: 4px !important;
       border-color: black !important;
       height: 100%;
}

body, .container, html {
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div id="app" class="container">
  <v-app>
    <v-divider class="test" vertical></v-divider>
  </v-app>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vuetify/dist/vuetify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I really appreciate it.